# jQuery Plugin init binding event to window scroll - how to pass $this?

Tags: jquery, plugins, scope, scrolltop

My first plugin done with a proper architecture, but I'm stuck at how to apply an event listener to $(window).scroll to pin the globalMessage to the top of the window. The full plugin in progress can be seen here: https://gist.github.com/937792, but the pertinent bits are the init, below.

What is the best way to set up a window event listener that modifies a css property of the target element?

```
(function($){

    var methods = {
        init: function(options) {

            var $this = this;
            var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.globalMessage.defaults, options);
            var data = $this.data('globalMessage');

            // init global data
            if ( ! data ) {
                $this.data('globalMessage', {
                    settings : opts
                });

                $(window).bind("scroll.globalMessage", function() {

                    // ----------
                    // HOW TO ACCESS both $this (defined outside this context)
                    // and the scrollTop value to change top css val?
                    //-----------
                    $this.css("top", $(window).scrollTop());

                });

                $this.bind('click.globalMessage', methods.hide);

            }

            return $this;
        },
        ...[other funcs]...
    }

    ...[main entry point etc]...

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: it's not at all clear to me what your problem actually is.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding what you're doing with the window scroll event but if you want the globalMessage to stay at the top of the window could you not just used position:fixed css?

Comment: @nicky - say you're scrolled halfway down the page and you want to display a message that is pinned to the top of the window. A fixed element with top:0 would not be in view in that case.

Comment: @notbrain maybe you're right its a getting a bit late here - http://jsfiddle.net/wUpgP/

Comment: @nicky you're perfectly lucid, seems I'm the one lacking in css foo; position:fixed is the better way. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing vars in right way to events:

```
$(window).bind("scroll.globalMessage", {foo:'bar'}, function(e) {
   alert(e.data.foo); // alert 'bar'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you think about it, there is no `this` in the context of your `methods` object. So you need to pass it in through the `init()` call:

```
(function($){

    var methods = {
        init: function(sel, options) {

            var $this = $(sel);
```

And then, when you call your plugin, pass `this` to your `init()` method:

```
$.fn.yourPlugin = function(method) {
    if (!this.length) {
        return this;
    }
    if (methods[method]) {
        return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
        return methods.init(this, arguments);
    } else {
        $.error('Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.yourPlugin');
    }
};
```

The only thing I would caution is that at the point the `$this` variable is set, it's actually a jQuery object, not a specific element. So I have used:

```
(function($){

    var methods = {
        init: function(sel, options) {

            var $sel = $(sel);
```

And, as far as using the `$this` within the event handler, you'll need to redefine it:

```
$(window).bind("scroll.globalMessage", function() {
    $this = $('#the_selector_for_your_element'); // Maybe $(this)?
    $this.css("top", $(window).scrollTop());
});
```

Comment: Re: passing this from $.fn.plugin: I think I am already doing that - because if I call console.log(this.attr("id")) as the first line in init, I get the id I expect (the one the plugin was attached to). Isn't "this" in the init context already a jQuery object?

Comment: Hmm, I had the same problem with a plugin I am working with and solved it with the above code ([you can see it here](http://jfcoder.com/jquery/dev/plugins/timeformatter/timeformatter.plugin.html)). As for the event handler, you need to redefine the $this for the event handler context, since when it is called it will be out of context by the time it's called.

Comment: @jared, check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/7CxuC/7/ Am I crazy or is that not equivalent to what you have without the need to pass this explicitly from $.fn.globalMessage? Appreciate the help btw...

Comment: yeah...the .apply function used to invoke the functions in the methods array takes care of setting "this" inside the init function. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply